# DynamoDB - how to get the item attributes if ConditionExpression failed on "put"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to save an item if the primary key doesn't exist. If this key already exists, I want to cancel the "put" and get the item that exists in the table.
I've noticed there is a field called "ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure" in transactWrite that may be the solution:

```
Use ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure to get the item attributes if the Put condition fails.
For ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure, the valid values are: NONE and ALL_OLD.
```

It didn't work and I get an error of `Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [ConditionalCheckFailed]`.

This is what I tried to do so far:

```
docClient.transactWrite({
      TransactItems: [{
        Put: {
          TableName: 'test.users',
          Item: {
            user_id,
            name,
          },
          ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(user_id)',
          ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure: 'ALL_OLD',
        }
      }]
    })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just do a GetItem after the PutItem if that failed? What's the error - `It didn't work` isn't very specific ;)

Comment: I added the error, thank's!
I don't want to handle the race condition of 
- getItem, the item doesn't exist.
- failed to save as someone already saved it.
- get the item again.

Comment: the docs say this field should be used for "Put condition fails" and you can't use Put and ConditionCheck for the same Item ```no two of them can operate on the same item```

Comment: Yeah, just noticed myself